# Laravel Collections: Shift Value *and* Key?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Do the laravel collection methods (or PHP array methods, for that matter) have a way to shift off the first key/value pair of a collection?

That is, if I have the following small program

```
$collection = collect(['key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2']);        

var_dump(
    $collection->first()
);

var_dump(
    $collection->shift()
);
```

I can `shift()` `value1` off the beginning of the collection, or grab it without removing it via `first()`.  What I'd like is way, with one line of code, to shift off or grab the **key** of the first value (i.e. `key1`).  I know I can do something like this

```
$result = (function($c){
    foreach($c as $key=>$value)
    {
        return $key;
    }
})($collection);
```

but I was hoping-that/wondering-if Laravel had something more elegant/compact.

Comment: Do you not care about the values at all?

Comment: @Devon I care about them some -- but if there's no way to grab both the value's just one line of additional code away with they key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grabbing an element (fist or last):

*First one*

```
$collection->take(1);
```

*Result*

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#926
     all: [
       "key1" => "value1",
     ],
   }
```

---

*Last one*

```
$collection->take(-1);
```

*Result*

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#924
     all: [
       "key2" => "value2",
     ],
   }
```

---

*Grabbing first key I*

```
$collection->take(1)->keys()->first();
```

*Result*

```
"key1"
```

---

*Grabbing first key II*

```
key($collection->take(1)->toArray());
```

*Result*

```
"key1"
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to grab the keys is using

```
$collectionOfKeys = $collection->keys();
```

To get the first key, you could do:

```
$key = $collection->keys()->first();
```

However, since keys() will return a new collection, it's not possible to shift the values off of the original collection in one line, but you could use forget with the $key or just shift the original collection afterwards.

```
$collection->forget($key);
// or $collection->shift();
```

Comment: That's what I would do as well. It's clean, self-explanatory and uses dedicated Laravel methods.

Comment: @lesssugar you would ask Laravel to build an array of keys with potentially millions of elements just because you need a first element? Why?

Comment: I would agree that splice() is the most efficient way of handling this,  I was putting up an example when Jean posted his answer.   This way works, but on a large collection would be inefficient.

Comment: @Axalix You got me.

Answer (score 3):

Splice can work for you:

```
$collection = collect(['key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2']); 

$chunked = $collection->splice(0, 1);

print_r($chunked);
//Array([key1] => value1)

print_r($collection->all());
//Array ( [key2] => value2 )
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-splice

Comment: Beat me to it, was just updating my answer.